# Android app is crashing on while opening paytm default activity. Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected Android API level 21+ but was 30

Tags: java, android, paytm

My app is working fine for the android versions upto 10. It is also working fine for android 11 in in most of the devices except Samsung with android version 11. App is crashing while I am clicking on the Paytm with exception. Logs are as below -

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected Android API level 21+ but was 30
ActivityTaskManager:   Force finishing activity com.paytm.pgsdk.PaytmPGActivity
```

Comment: Are you using the latest one in all [SDK](https://developer.paytm.com/docs/all-in-one-sdk/?ref=allInOneSdk)? As old one is deprecated.

Comment: latest one only, All-in-one-sdk 1.6.0

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution for this issue. I updated okhttp libraries to latest versions and crash is resolved.